# stop video on hash change

Tags: javascript, youtube

I added some youtube videos with this code:

```
const youtube = document.querySelectorAll('.youtube');

  for (let i = 0; i < youtube.length; i++) {
    const source = `https://img.youtube.com/vi/${youtube[i].dataset.embed}/hqdefault.jpg`;
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = source;
    image.addEventListener('load', function() {
      youtube[i].appendChild(image);
    }(i)); // end eventListener

youtube[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

  iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
  iframe.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', '');
  iframe.setAttribute('src', `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${this.dataset.embed}?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1`);
    this.innerHTML = '';
    this.appendChild(iframe);
 });
}
```

I'm loading an image as a placeholder and then when you click on the image you request for the video, how can I stop the video when window.onhashchange? It's one page with multiple divs that are visible/hidden based on thehash, so I don't reload the page but I simply change what I show on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I found out a simple way to do it:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

it forces to reload the page and all the videos are reset to the original state with the placeholder